# Is there a generally useful formula for width of generic  Windows buttons, checkboxes, and labels based on length of text?

Tags: c#, dynamic, text, width, controls

I am dynamically creating various Windows controls where the user supplies the text that will display on a button, alongside a checkbox, inside a label, etc.

With the default Windows font, is there a "good-enough" (this is just a mockup, anyway - doesn't have to always be perfect) formula to determine what the width of the control should be relative to the width of the text? e.g., should it be something like:

```
Control.Width = text.Length * 3
```

...or...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do this manually.

Setting the `AutoSize` property to `true` on your [Control will do this for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.autosize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: But that's only useful if you're OK with the awful layout that is sure to result.  Only by knowing the size could you relate controls to one another based on their size, for example to provide some alignment.

Comment: That works perfect for me; as I said, this is just a mockup, and "good enough" is just that. The simplest way is often best.

Answer (score 3):

You can always measure the text size with [TextRenderer.MeasureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sy6awsb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Once you have how much wide the string will be you just need to add some extra width to allow control border's and else.

Comment: MeasureText, not MeasureSize

Comment: `Grpahics.MeasureString` also another option.